# How to build a mandatory terms & conditions page for an app using PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I have built an app using PhoneGap Build and wish for the following modification.

On the first launch on the device, or first launch after an update, I would like to have a screen displaying the terms & conditions (and possibly a field to enter an email address). At the bottom of the screen, there will be an Accept or Decline, after which a user will either enter or exit the application. The answer should be stored (possibly using the 'file' API: http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file?)

On subsequent loads, the app should first check the data stored using the 'file' API to see if terms have been previously Accepted. If so, the user should enter the app without any prompt. If not, the user should be prompted by the terms & conditions again.

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you are on the right track. Just make sure you are using the right documentation for the version of phonegap you are using. The one you linked above is for version 1.0...

First, you want to use the local storage API, not the file API. Assuming you are using Phonegap Build 3.0 you can find the documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Next, every time your index.html page loads, you want to check the local storage to see if they have agreed to your terms and what version of the apps terms they agreed to.

```
tx.executeSql('Select agreedBool FROM termsTable WHERE version = "1.0.0"', [], successFunction, errorFunction);
```

If agreedBool = true, do nothing. If agreedBool = false, then show your terms pop-up or transfer them to your terms.html page or however you want to show it. When then they click agree, save that value to the database and close your pop-up or redirect back to index.html.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO termsTable (agreedBool, version) VALUES (true, "1.0.0")');
```

As for the user choosing not to agree to the terms, I wouldnt give them an agree and disagree button. Only give them an agree button. If they dont agree, then they can close your app themselves.

Comment: Hi Dom. Unfortunately Phonegap Build 3.0 does not currently support the 'Storage' API. Is there any way to accomplish this with 'File' API, or another API?

Comment: The storage API is fully supported in 3.0. No need for a plugin or anything. Just follow the examples in the documentation here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html. I have a PGB3.0 app using it.